# Split a string in between two characters in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, string, split

I have a string of type **"24;#usernamehere,#AWRFR\user,#,#,#usernamehere"**

I want to split this string on the first appearance on **`#`** and  **`,`** i.e i want a string to be fetched which is inbetween these two characters.

So for the above string i want the OUTPUT as:

**`usernamehere`**

How can i split a string in between two characters using `Regex` function?

Comment: Sounds like a job for regex...

Comment: Have you tried the method `String.Split()`? - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7h14879.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple Regex Pattern might do the job:

```
var pattern = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("#(?<name>.+?),");
```

test:

```
string s = @"24;#usernamehere,#AWRFR\user,#,#,#usernamehere";
pattern.Match(s).Groups["name"].Value;   //usernamehere
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Linq:

```
using System.Linq;
var input = @"24;#usernamehere,#AWRFR\user,#,#,#usernamehere";
```

You can split it with a single line:

```
var x = input.Split('#').Where(e => e.Contains(',')).Select(e => e.Split(',').First());
```

which is the same as:

```
var x = from e in input.Split('#') 
        where e.Contains(',') 
        select e.Split(',').First();
```

in both cases the result would be:

```
x = {"usernamehere", "AWRFR\user", "", ""}
```

Which is exactly an array with all substrings enclosed by `#` and `,`.
Then if you want the first element just add `.First()` or do:

```
x.First();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the first index of '#' & ','. Then use substring method to get your required trimmed string. Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) for more details on substring method

```
string s = @"24;#usernamehere,#AWRFR\user,#,#,#usernamehere";
string finalString = s.Substring(s.IndexOf('#') + 1, s.IndexOf(',') - s.IndexOf('#') - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the way you asked for it, but should do what you want...

```
string input = @"24;#usernamehere,#AWRFR\user,#,#,#usernamehere";
string username = input.Substring(input.LastIndexOf("#") + 1);
```

If you wanted you could get the position of the first # and the ,

```
int hashPosition = input.IndexOf("#") + 1;
int commaPosition = input.IndexOf(",");

string username = input.Substring(hashPosition, commaPosition - hashPosition));
```